# Why can't I unpivot (melt) this panda dataframe (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda data frame that I made and I pivoted it the exact way I want it. Now, I want to unpivot everything to get the position data (row and column) with the newly formed data frame and see which. For example, I want for the first row (in the new data frame that is unpivoted with the position data) to have 1 under "row", 1 under "a", and 1 as the value (example below). Can someone please figure out how I can unpivot to get the row and column values? I have tried used pd.melt but it didn't seem to work (it made no difference). Please respond soon. Thanks! Directly below is code to make the pivoted data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df67 = {'row':row,}
df67 = pd.DataFrame(df67,columns=['row'])
df67['a'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df67['b'] =[13, 18, 5, 10, 6]
#df67 (dataframe before pivot)
df68 = df67.pivot(index='row', columns = 'a')
#df68 (dataframe after pivot)
```

`What I want the result to be for the first line:
row | a | value
1   | 1 | 13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df68.stack().reset_index()
print (df)
   row  a     b
0    1  1  13.0
1    2  2  18.0
2    3  3   5.0
3    4  4  10.0
4    5  5   6.0
```

EDIT:

For avoid removed missing values use `dropna=False` parameter:

```
df = df68.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
print (df)
    row  a     b
0     1  1  13.0
1     1  2   NaN
2     1  3   NaN
3     1  4   NaN
4     1  5   NaN
5     2  1   NaN
6     2  2  18.0
7     2  3   NaN
8     2  4   NaN
9     2  5   NaN
10    3  1   NaN
11    3  2   NaN
12    3  3   5.0
13    3  4   NaN
14    3  5   NaN
15    4  1   NaN
16    4  2   NaN
17    4  3   NaN
18    4  4  10.0
19    4  5   NaN
20    5  1   NaN
21    5  2   NaN
22    5  3   NaN
23    5  4   NaN
24    5  5   6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly jezrael and the code looks good. but I was wondering if I could also include null values. I hope that this won't be too much of a problem to add to the code. Thanks!